# Odd shadow being cast: cube vs plane

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, shadows

I have a cube transposing a plane and just one light. The shadow casted is weird. There is something missing at the corner. When I switch to Cycles, I got the correct shadows.

[image]
[image]

Comment: That artifact is called "Peter Panning", by the way.

Answer (score 6):

You need to enable the *Contact Shadows* option of the light, and increase the *Distance* value:

[image]

Comment: I have just started learning Blender. It might be very basic, right? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Further to  [@moonboots' suggestion](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/277507/35559) ...

In EEVEE, direct-light shadows are achieved by shadow mapping, which can give rise to artefacts where the fakery fails. 'Bias' is one of the fudge-factors made available to relieve some [self-shadowing artefacts](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-16-shadow-mapping/#result---shadow-acne), but may introduce some undesirable side-effects of its own.. (which you can see if you read down, from the link)

Your offset shadow is one of the side-effects, if Bias is set too high for the circumstances.

The maps are constructed per shadow-casting lamp, so the adjustments can be found in the lamp's settings:

[image]

Comment: Really thanks! Both answers were very helpful.